How can I find a door for an oddly-sized opening?
I have this opening between my living room and guest room and we want to put a door in it to be able to use it as a spare bedroom for guests. We wanted French doors but Home Depot said the opening was either too small or too wide for whatever they can order.
I have 10 days to get a door installed. What's the best option for me? for a rough opening of 47 1/2 x 81, what doors would you recommend? I'm in the south Jersey area if that matters.

Do you actually want French doors, which are made of glass panes, or did you actually just mean double doors? Also, is the opening framed with a jamb, or is it simply drywall? Please revise to add detail and photos, if possible.

What's in the doorway now? How are you measuring the rough opening? Is it finished with drywall or is there an existing door. You can do a pair of bi-fold doors but you need 48" opening.

See also What interior door will fit a rough opening of 47-3/4"?.

This isn't really a "shopping" question to me, more like a "what do I need to do to DIY this?"

I suspect you mean double doors and not French doors (which are filled with glass panes). At any rate, double doors tend to be a bit rattly and offer less privacy unless they have an integrated mullion, which makes operation a bit more cumbersome. It's already more cumbersome for a small opening since you almost always have to open both doors to pass comfortably.
I suggest that you frame down the opening for a standard 36" door. If you care to post details about your opening in your question I'm happy to offer more detail about doing that. There are ways to avoid drywall work if that's a concern.

My suggestion would be to have 2 barn doors installed. I seen HD has solid core panel doors that could work, that is if they're available 24" wide.
They can be mounted on the track so they meet in the middle or if there is enough room on one side, join them together to travel as one.
There are privacy locks that act on the jamb to make for some privacy.

That may work if there's sufficient wall space to either side of the opening.

You'll never find French doors in that narrow a size, so unless you simply need them to have glass in them, roll your own out of a pair of 24x80 slab doors.  Use a table saw or circular saw to cut a bit off the side of each door.
